# How to add a javascript snippet to the footer that requires jQuery

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I know I can add a script file to the footer of wordpress that requires jquery using this code:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
       array('jquery'),
       '1.0',
       true);
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

But what if I want to add just a normal snippet of jquery inline, not a file. How can this be done.

## Edit

I know I can use this script to add something to the footer:

```
<?php
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // This depends on jquery
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'myscript');
```

But how do I specify the script that is used **requires jquery** to run.

Comment: There is no built in function to do this that I know, it is why `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` exist, but you can check using jquery itself.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I do not think you understand my question. I have read the codex, and know about the option. But I do not want to `wp_enqueue_script` a script file into the footer, I want to add a snippet into the footer that requires jquery. *I downvoted the answer directly taken from the codex. I read the codex, and did not find an answer, that's why I ask a question. If you redirect me to the codex again I downvote.*

Comment: Thanks wyck, I think this is the case, thank you for understanding the question correctly. I think I will just use an external JS script instead than to be sure the script can be run.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is actually a combination of `wp_enqueue_script` and the footer actions that Saif and v0idless already referenced.  I frequently use jQuery in my themes and plugins, but I put all of the other scripts in the footer as well.

The best way to actually queue things up would be this:

```
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ) {
    // script dependent on jQuery
  }
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );

function myscript_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'myscript_jquery' );
```

But this code snipped assumes that you're the one queueing the script, i.e. you're doing this in your own plugin or theme.

At the moment, there is no way to add an in-line script to the WordPress footer and also load it with dependencies.  But there is an alternative, if you're willing.

## The alternative

When WordPress works with scripts, it loads them internally to an object to keep track of them.  There are essentially 3 lists inside the object:

- registered
- queue
- done
- to_do

When you first *register* a script with `wp_register_scripts()` it's placed in the registered list.  When you `wp_enqueue_script()` the script, it's copied to the queue list.  After it's been printed to the page, it's added to the done list.

So, rather than queueing your footer script to require jQuery, you can *document* that it needs to use jQuery and just check programatically to make sure jQuery is loaded.

This uses [`wp_script_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) to check where the script is listed.

```
function myscript() {
    if( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // script dependent on jQuery
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
```

You *might* be able to use this same code to force jQuery to load in the footer as well, but I haven't tested that ... so your mileage my vary.

Comment: does your provided code snippet is accepted by WordPress plugin development standards ? If yes, then I will be using it in my plugin ... please give me a reply upon this ...

Comment: The last snippet? No. WordPress plugins should _always_ enqueue script requirements. Forcing jQuery to load outside of the queue system in this way is only something you should do on your own site where you control 100% of the environment. It is _never_ appropriate for a plugin to do that.

Comment: then can u give me some working example for that please ... ????

Comment: Because I am developing my first ever WordPress plugin and I would love to have that accepted by the WordPress team ... waiting for any of your response please .... have your say about this so that I can create and make accepted my plugin ...

Answer (score 15):

Since wordpress 4.5 you can add inline script by `wp_add_inline_script()`. To add a javascript snippet to the footer that requires jQuery, this code helps you

```
function enqueue_jquery_in_footer( &$scripts ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() )
        $scripts->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
}
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery_in_footer' );

function theme_prefix_enqueue_script() {
   if(!wp_script_is('jquery', 'done')) {
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-migrate', 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){});' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_prefix_enqueue_script' );
```

[wp_add_inline_script with wordpress jquery](http://www.mavengang.com/2016/06/25/wp_add_inline_script-wordpress-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `wp_footer` action like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse33008');
function wpse33008() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /** INSERT SCRIPT HERE **/
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. I asked how I could specify the script required jQuery. If the user does not have jquery running your implementation will not run.

Answer (score 1):

I know *OP* wants to specify a requirement on jQuery, and WordPress' authors should have allowed snippets to be enqueued adjacent to script files, but they didn't, so I recommend not trying to force it. If you don't want to mess with the queue or its order at all, like me (because I'm using other plugins that combine and optimise scripts), then the answer really is to use the `wp_footer` action like so:

```
<?php

add_action(
    'wp_footer'
    , function() {
        ?>
        <script>
            if (window.jQuery) {
                // your snippet
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    , 21 # after enqueued footer scripts
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `wp_footer` action for doing this. Check the codex for [wp_footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer).

Comment: I know, but how can you specify that the script you add to the footer is depending on jquery. Check my edit to be more spicific.

Comment: Do you even bother to read around the codex before voting down people's answers? Have you ever read about the `in_footer` argument to `wp_enqueue_script`? Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script. It tells you how to use it with the `wp_footer` action.