# How to add javascript just before the closing body tag in the footer of WordPress

Tags: javascript, footer

[I'm following some of the other people's advice here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/how-to-add-a-javascript-snippet-to-the-footer-that-requires-jquery) about adding my js file before the closing body tag but it doesn't seem to work for me.

If someone would be so kind as to check this for me please?

```
<?php
  /*load the js file into the footer*/
  function myscript() 
  {
   if( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
  ?>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <?php
  }
 }
  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
?>
```

Many thanks

**EDIT:------------------------------------------------**

This is the short solution..
`<script language="javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/scripts.js"></script>`

not the right answer though is it?

**EDIT---------------------------------------------------**

This is what I am trying based on the WP codex examples and your points Fischi but think I am still doing something wrong..

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'myscript',
    get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/scripts.js',
    array( 'jquery' ), 
    '', 
    true
);
 }    

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

The file still doesn't load into the footer.

Comment: *The file doesn't load* - does this mean the `<script>` tags don't appear in the footer - or is the script is not being found?. Finally does your theme call [`wp_footer();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)

Comment: Hi Stephen. My theme is using <?php get_footer(); ?>. Let me try wp_footer(); and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should always add javascript (and styles) with the Wordpress function `wp_enqueue_script()`

Works like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
 $handle // the name of your enqueued file, in your case 'myscript'
,$src    // source of your file, can be external, or for your example: get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/scripts.js'
,$deps   // does your javascript depend on another javascriptfile? for example jquery? pass an array of arguments specifying all the dependencies: array( 'jquery' )
,$ver   // version number of your javascript
,$in_footer // this is what you need: true
);
```

after setting the `$in_footer` to true, it gets enqueued in the `wp_footer()` action, usually right before the ending of the body tag.

so, for you:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```

does the trick.

**Note:** Not all themes do (*though all themes should*) call [`wp_footer();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in their footer / just above the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks very much Fischi. See my edit above....StackExchange comments are crap at clean markup.

Comment: Hi Fischi. My theme is using <?php get_footer(); ?>. I've tried  wp_footer(); but this didn't work, the footer did not appear at all.

Comment: @SixfootJames no problem. note that the difference between `get_footer()` and `wp_footer()` is that `get_footer()` calls the template file `footer.php`, while `wp_footer()` is an action performed by wordpress to insert every javascript and style that are defined to appear in the footer. usually `wp_footer()` is located in the `footer.php`, just before the closing of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: as steven harris mentioned, not all themes call `wp_footer()`. if yours doesn't insert this before the `</body>` tag.