# jQuery does not enqueue for my purpose... (before an inline script in the footer)

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Following [How to add a javascript snippet to the footer that requires jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/how-to-add-a-javascript-snippet-to-the-footer-that-requires-jquery)
I am trying to load jQuery before my script does stuff but it's not working.

[This is it working when I include jQuery manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4gmZ.png)

[This is it not working when I do it the right way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvtG7.png)

In that previous question, the answerer says I should put my script material inside an `if( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {`, and I tried that too but the part within the `if` never gets executed.

Comment: Why not just hook everything to wp_enqueue_scripts and put it in separate javascript files if you're just going to wrap it in jQuery(document).ready(function($).. anyway?

Comment: Do you see jQuery in source at all when queueing? Also you should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook rather than more generic `wp_head`.

Comment: @Rarst TRhank you!! I saw that [it loads *after* my code.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VDJ4v.png). 

I should put `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );` outside of `myscript_jquery()` function. [It's working now.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Kxm.png) :)

Comment: @AndrewBartel Part of my script has to be dynamically made, using variables from my plugin. (I'm looking into how to achieve my goal without that, but this is still a valid approach, no?)

Comment: use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data from php to javascript, no need to print it directly to the page yourself.