# how to remove default jquery and add js in footer?

Tags: jquery, footer

I want to remove default jQuery, because I am adding new or latest jQuery. Also I want include some js in my footer. How can I do that?

I want to add another different js like a slider js or css in my footer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a javascript snippet to the footer that requires jQuery](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/how-to-add-a-javascript-snippet-to-the-footer-that-requires-jquery)

Comment: Note: It is generally *not* recommended to remove/replace the jQuery version bundled with WordPress core.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will do the trick when added to your functions file:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Beat me too it. To elaborate, you can use this method to de_register basically ANY script that's properly loaded via wp's internal register function. That includes scripts registered via plugins or even themes. Do note, the trick sometimes is finding the proper priority that they are hooked in under.

Comment: I was just reading about this the other day and learnt this from reading https://github.com/amberweinberg/Hijinks--A-Developer-s-Blank-WordPress-Theme/blob/master/super-hijinksified/functions.php

Comment: i want to add jquery in header but another js in footer like any plugin js.

Comment: You could just hard code the one for the footer or header and use  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); in the functions file to remove the default WordPress jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I am searching I get one blog here I get two different code. one for

### [Remove Default Jquery In Wordpress](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-remove-default-jquery-in.html)

Here I am the same code for below

```
<?php
  function myphpinformation_scripts() {    
    if( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
      wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', false );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myphpinformation_scripts' );
?>
```

### [Add Jquery In Footer In Wordpress](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-add-jquery-in-footer-in-wordpress.html)

here I know how to add js in WordPress in the footer. I think removing default jquery and add js in the footer in WordPress is a different question.

Here I can found that

```
<?php
  function myphpinformation_scripts() {    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',array('jquery'),'',true);
  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myphpinformation_scripts' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove WordPress default jQuery from front end**

We can remove default wordpress jQuery from the frontend so that to avoid conflict with the jQuery in the theme. In order to remove the default jQuery add the following code in the function.php file in the theme folder.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_jquery');
function no_more_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```