# wp_deregister_script('jquery') not working

Tags: jquery

I use this code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'WPScripts_enqueue' ) ) {
    function WPScripts_enqueue() {

        // Removing default jQuery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        // Enqueue the new jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', false, '3.2.1', false);

        // Enqueue custom Bootstrap file
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), false, 'all');

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WPScripts_enqueue');
```

however, wp still load jquery from wp core:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=TR&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site%2Fhomepage%2F&tab=desktop

https://i.ibb.co/qxhCY6R/image.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove default jquery and add js in footer?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189310/how-to-remove-default-jquery-and-add-js-in-footer)

Comment: no, if you know answer please write me

Answer (score 1):

**Use the Following sequence to override jquery**
Install latest jQuery version 3.4.1.
Update the following sequence of code and try!!!!

```
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery',("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"), 
   false);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

I hope it will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add priority to add_action.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WPScripts_enqueue', 999);
```

Or

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WPScripts_enqueue', -1);
```

Comment: it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Second documentation example (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/), use hook `wp_print_scripts` with priority `100`. Like this:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to first dequeue the script first & then deregister the script as given as bellow

```
           wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery');

           wp_deregister_script(‘jquery’);
```

Try this!!

Comment: it doesnt work.it is still same

Comment: Are you sure that `WPScripts_enqueue` is being executed?