# Click a radio button must set textfield value

Tags: php, jquery, radio

I have these radio-buttons in my checkout page:

```
<input id="95292" type="radio" name="GLSShop" value="95292" onclick="SaveShopID('95292')">
<input id="95064" type="radio" name="GLSShop" value="95064" onclick="SaveShopID('95064')">
<input id="95403" type="radio" name="GLSShop" value="95403" onclick="SaveShopID('95403')">
```

When user click e.g. button no. 2 I want the value of a textfield to be set to '95064'

I was thinking about making a java- or jqueryscript something like this:

```
function SaveShopID($ShopID){
     $("#order_comments").val($ShopID);
};
```

1: Would this be the best and easiest way of doing it?

2: If so, how would the script look like, I would be surprised if mine is correct ;-)

3: where do I place the script?

4: How do I add/enqueue the script? I've seen examples using **add_action**("wp_enqueue_scripts'.....) but I'm not sure how to do it.

I use a child-scheme of course.

And I have full control of the radio button's HTML so it can be easily changed to something else if prefered ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many approach for your js part on input, and you were correct, but we can't disccuss a lot about it here. And a part for your question related to WordPress, yes you are right. You can use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to enqueue your js function inside js file, remember to use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) as part url of your js file since you are in child theme, and set to *in footer* ( take your time to search for example code here, a lot! ).

But for a pieces code, I would like just fire [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/), take a look [*@EAMann answer*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33032/18731).

Your code may like this ( put in `functions.php` theme file ):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse222047_script_footer' );
function wpse222047_script_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ){
      function SaveShopID($ShopID){
          jQuery("#order_comments").val($ShopID);
      }
  }
</script>
<?php
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can someone explain the"( undefined !== window.jQuery )" line?
What does "undefined" and "Window.jQuery" reference to?

Comment: to explain about it I just can give you reference here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1562904