# WordPress Ajax Not Working ( Custom Admin page)

Tags: ajax, wp-admin

I tried to do a small thing using Ajax. I just try to replace a div.

This is what I have done so far.

I created a admin menu using `add_menu_page`.

Then I add a form to that page with a text field. I just need to replace a div when click the submit button. But it did not works. When I check console in browser it says **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined**

---

```
function myajaxfunction() {
    $.ajax({ //ajax request
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'rs_like_request',
            'post_type' : $('#post_type').val() // value of text box having id "post_type"

        },
        success:function(data) {  //result
         $(".showdiv").html(data); //showdiv is the class of the div where we want to show the results
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  

}
```

---

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Write post type : </label>
    <input type="text" name="post_type" id="post_type" value=""/>
    <input type="button" value="Show Post Titles" onclick="myajaxfunction()"/>

    <div class="showdiv"></div>

</form>
```

---

```
function rs_like_count() {

    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {   // $_REQUEST is having all the data sent using ajax
        $post_type= $_REQUEST['post_type'];
        echo $post_type;

}
 die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rs_like_request', 'rs_like_count' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

*@Sasa1234*, it happen cause your jQuery is undefined. Please take a look [*@EAMann answer*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33032/18731). So, your JS code should like this:

```
function myajaxfunction() {
    if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ) {
        jQuery.ajax({ //ajax request
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action':'rs_like_request',
                'post_type' : jQuery('#post_type').val() // value of text box having id "post_type"

            },
            success:function(data) {  //result
             jQuery(".showdiv").html(data); //showdiv is the class of the div where we want to show the results
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added it. But still there is same error :-(

Comment: Check your jQuery file. if your form in front end, then you should add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_rs_like_request', 'rs_like_count' );` and make it sure your js code put in footer.

Comment: Thanks, No, it is an admin page. Then I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to that page(plugin page). Now it is working. Is it a problem adding it?

Comment: I don't recommend you use that, WordPress have jQuery built-in, I think you need to check it if it's exists.

Comment: `function textdomain_load_jquery() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'textdomain_load_jquery' );` This is not working. Do you have any idea about that? But `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>` working.

Comment: By default, jQuery file was exists in all WordPress page actually. If you are in admin area, you should use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: and if `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' )` not work, you can use `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core' )`.