# How to change a wordress plugin php code in my child's functions.php file?

Tags: plugins, php, html, email

I'm trying to edit EmailOctopus plugin, this is part of their "form.php" code:

```js
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    die('No direct access.');
}

/**
 * Filter: emailoctopus_class_names
 *
 * Add more class names.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param array $main_class_names Array of class names
 * @param int   $form_id          The form ID
 */
$main_class_names = apply_filters('emailoctopus_class_names', $main_class_names, $form_id);
?>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $main_class_names));?>" <?php echo $appearance === 'custom' ? sprintf('style="%s"', implode(' ', $main_class_styles)) : '';?>>
    <form method="post" action="https://emailoctopus.com/lists/<?php echo esc_attr($list_id); ?>/members/external-add" class="emailoctopus-form">
        <div class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
            <textarea class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" name="message_consent_required" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo esc_textarea(wp_kses_post($message_consent_required)); ?></textarea>
            <textarea class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" name="message_missing_email" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo esc_textarea(wp_kses_post($message_missing_email)); ?></textarea>
            <textarea class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" name="message_invalid_email" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo esc_textarea(wp_kses_post($message_invalid_email)); ?></textarea>
            <textarea class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" name="message_bot" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo esc_textarea(wp_kses_post($message_bot)); ?></textarea>
            <textarea class="emailoctopus-form-textarea-hidden" name="message_success" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo esc_textarea(wp_kses_post($message_success)); ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <?php
        $show_title = isset($show_title) ? $show_title : true;
        $show_description = isset($show_description) ? $show_description : true;

        if ($show_title) {
            printf('<h2 class="emailoctopus-heading">%s</h2>', wp_kses_post($form_data['title']));
        }
        if ($show_description) {
            printf('<p>%s</p>', wp_kses_post($form_data['description']));
        }
        ?>
        <p class="emailoctopus-success-message"></p>
        <p class="emailoctopus-error-message"></p>
        <div class="emailoctopus-form-copy-wrapper">
            <input type="hidden" name="emailoctopus_form_id" value="<?php echo absint($form_id); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="emailoctopus_list_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($list_id); ?>" />
            <?php
            foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                echo '<div class="emailoctopus-form-row">';
                echo sprintf(
                    '<label><span class="emailoctopus-label">%s %s</span><br /><input type="%s" name="%s" class="emailoctopus-custom-fields" tabindex="%d" /></label>',
                    esc_html($custom_field['label']),
                    $custom_field['tag'] === 'EmailAddress' ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '',
                    esc_attr(strtolower($custom_field['type'])),
                    esc_attr($custom_field['tag']),
                    absint($tabindex)
                );
                echo '</div>';
                $tabindex += 1;
            }

            if (isset($show_consent) && $show_consent) {
                ?>
                <div class="emailoctopus-form-row">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="consent" class="emailoctopus-consent" tabindex="<?php echo absint($tabindex); ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo wp_kses_post($consent_content); ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <?php
                $tabindex += 1;
            }
            ?>
            <div class="emailoctopus-form-row-hp" aria-hidden="true">
                <!-- Do not remove this field, otherwise you risk bot signups -->
                <input type="text" name="hp<?php echo esc_attr($list_id); ?>" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="nope">
            </div>
            <div class="emailoctopus-form-row-subscribe">
                <?php
                if ($redirect) {
                    echo sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="successRedirectUrl" class="emailoctopus-success-redirect-url" value="%s" />', esc_attr($redirect_url));
                }
                ?>
                <button type="submit" tabindex="<?php echo absint($tabindex); ?>" style="<?php echo $appearance === 'custom' ? sprintf('background: %s; color: %s;', esc_attr($button_color), esc_attr($button_text_color)) : ''; ?>"><?php echo esc_html($message_submit); ?></button>
            </div>
            <?php
            if (isset($show_branding) && $show_branding) {
                ?>
                <div class="emailoctopus-referral">
                    <?php echo sprintf(__('Powered by %sEmailOctopus%s', 'emailoctopus'), '<a href="https://emailoctopus.com?utm_source=form&utm_medium=wordpress_plugin" target="_blank" rel="noopener">', '</a>'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Only thing I want do to is edit this HTML and add a placeholder="something" here:

```js
'<label><span class="emailoctopus-label">%s %s</span><br /><input type="%s" name="%s" class="emailoctopus-custom-fields" tabindex="%d" /></label>',
```

I could do this manually but I don't want to edit the plugin directly but rather I want to do it in functions.php of my child WordPress theme, how can I do that there?

EDIT: My attempt:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 'my_theme_add_placeholder' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', 'C:/MAMP/htdocs/site/wp-content/plugins/emailoctopus/templates' . '/form.php', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    jQuery('class:emailoctopus-custom-fields').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );

?>
```

Comment: There's nothing in the original code that you've included that suggests that this is possible. However other parts of the code might allow you to replace the whole form. I suggest contacting the plugin author for assistance.

Comment: I've edited the code now so it shows the whole code.

Comment: I don't think this has changed anything. If you were able to replace the whole form it looks like that'd be in the code that includes this file: I don't see anything here.

Comment: Can I do something with jquery in my functions.php, I've added this but it doesn't work?

$('input:%s').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');

Comment: The %s is substituted by sprintf that string is in. You'll need to take the type and or name fields from the generated element instead. If you haven't spoken to Octopus forms to ask them to add something then I would though - it's a sensible thing to want here.

Comment: I've tried this too but it doesn't work? 
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
function my_theme_add_placeholder() {
    wp_enqueue_style($('class:emailoctopus-custom-fields').attr('placeholder','Some New Text'));
}


?>

Comment: I can't quite read that - where is the second function being called? It might be easier to read if you edit it into the question. However you'd need something like this to include a short snippet like that, you can't just wp_enqueue_style a string I don't think: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/33008

Comment: I've edited my post, still doesn't work?